# How to check a property in an ngFor loop using an observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

There is this list of card objects that are returned from an API.

One of the cards should be set inactive. In the card component that is done via an observable:

```js
@Component({
  selector: "app-card",
  template: `
    <article [ngClass]="{ inactive: inactive$ | async }">
      <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    </article>`,
  styleUrls: ["./card.component.css"]
})
export class CardComponent {
  @Input() title: string;

  @Input() inactive$: Observable<boolean>;
}
```

Now in the component where the cards are rendered there needs to be a function to conditionally check whether the card is active or not.

**./app/app.component.ts**

```js
@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  template: `<app-card
    *ngFor="let card of cards$ | async"
    [title]="card.title"
    [inactive$]="checkIfInactive$(card.inactive)"
  ></app-card>`,
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  cards$ = new BehaviorSubject([]);

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cards$.next([
      { title: "Card title 1" },
      { title: "Card title 2", inactive: true }
    ]);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.cards$.complete();
  }

  // Each time this function is run, a new behaviorsubject is created? :(
  checkIfInactive$(inactiveCard: boolean) {
    if (inactiveCard) {
      return new BehaviorSubject(true).asObservable();
    } else {
      return new BehaviorSubject(false).asObservable();
    }
  }
}
```

Now the number #1 rule of rxjs seems to be to always unsubscribe/complete an observable. The function `checkIfInactive$()` returns a new observable each time that function is called. That does not seem right.

What is the right way to approach this?

---

Working codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-resonance-6xgv55?file=/src/app/app.component.ts:0-887

Comment: How about using an [of](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/of) instead of `return new BehaviorSubject(true).asObservable();`?

Comment: Like... `return of(true);` or `return of(false);` depending upon the condition.

Comment: Would you be able to clarify why you need an observable for inactive passed into the card component?

Comment: @Plabbee Good question. It's because the card component should also react to updates. The card array could for example also get an active property which might change over time. I'll update the code with that example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass a regular input to the inactive property of app-card instead of an Observable.

```
  import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

  @Component({
    selector: 'app-card',
    templateUrl: './card.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./card.component.css']
  })
  export class CardComponent {
    @Input() title: string;

    @Input() inactive: boolean;

  }
```

And the .html

```
<article [ngClass]="{ inactive: inactive }">
  <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
</article>
```

With this change you would be able to solve your working scenario.

In addition, if you need to react to updates on your Inputs and perform other operations in your component besides display the value in the template, you could use OnChanges lifecycle hook and watch for the value of inactive.

```
  @Component({
    selector: 'app-card',
    templateUrl: './card.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./card.component.css']
  })
  export class CardComponent implements OnChanges {
    @Input() title: string;

    @Input() inactive: boolean;

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
      if (changes.inactive?.currentValue) {
        // Do your thing
      } else {
        // Do something else
      }
    }
  }
```

Be careful passing an Observable as an Input.
There are a few things that you have to be aware of in this case.

The most important thing from my point of view is that, in order to get the values from an Observable you could either subscribe or reflect the values on the template with `| async`. If you only want to reflect the values on the template, you could go with `| async`, but if this is the case you could simply pass the value as an Input and dont use an Observable in the first place.
In the other hand, if you need to do something else with the values emitted by the Observable you have to subscribe to it, and for that you also need to use `OnChanges` lifecycle hook, in order to ensure that you are handling the case that your Input changes.

Aside note: Observables like Objects and Arrays are passed by reference, so you have to ensure that you are providing a new reference in the Input in order to detect the changes.

Comment: Thank you, this works. I was hoping to do it using rxjs, also to get a better understanding of that library. I'll leave this question open for a bit otherwise accept this as the answer.

Comment: Yes, sure. In my opinion you dont need an Observable in this case. Im going to add a new answer explaining this a little bit more.

Comment: Or just edit this one.